# Delphi: программное создание ярлыка

Tags: delphi

Создаю ярлык для программы этой функцией:

```
function CreateShortcut(const CmdLine, Args, WorkDir, LinkFile: string): IPersistFile;
var
  MyObject: IUnknown;
  MySLink: IShellLink;
  MyPFile: IPersistFile;
  WideFile: WideString;
begin
  MyObject := CreateComObject(CLSID_ShellLink);
  MySLink := MyObject as IShellLink;
  MyPFile := MyObject as IPersistFile;
  with MySLink do
  begin
    SetPath(PChar(CmdLine));
    SetArguments(PChar(Args));
    SetWorkingDirectory(PChar(WorkDir));
  end;
  WideFile := LinkFile;
  MyPFile.Save(PWChar(WideFile), False);
  Result := MyPFile;
end;
```

Вот так вызываю:

```
CreateShortcut('D:\Equinox.exe', '', 'D:\', 'D:\temp.lnk');
```

Проблема в том, что ярлык создаётся, но патч автоматически берётся в двойные кавычки (т.е. в поле патч что-то типо этого: "D:\program.exe").
Как сделать так, чтобы этих двойных кавычек, которые добавляются автоматически, не было?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос а что если путь в двойных кавычках ярлык перестает работать?
Тем более это требование самой винды о двойных кавычках, попробуйте вручную в свойствах ярлыка их удалить и увидите что винда их допишет.

Comment: ничего она не допишет. с чего вы это взяли? двойные кавычки никакие это не обязательные требования винды. 
мне нужно убрать двойные кавычки чтобы можно было запускать командную строку и прописывать команды. и делать это через путь. 
если в ручную прописываю путь то всё работает, а если с дельфи создаю, то вылазять эти долбаные кавычки и не работает то, что я хочу

Comment: Ищите проблему там где ее нет.
дополнительные команды дописываются после кавычек и все нормально работает, только что посмотрел в свойствах ярлыка.
Не помню как ХР но вин7 дописывает кавычки сама.

Comment: тем более в вашей функции есть параметр **Args**  вот туда и дописывайте дополнительные команды, и будет вам нормальный ярлык с доп командами.

Comment: спасибо, вроде получилось что хотел )